# Which is better between an android app and a server? Socket or timer?

Tags: android, asp.net, sockets, alarmmanager

I'm going to make an android app that needs to work like an instant messaging (Chat) application, but a little different. It needs to send and receive some short messages, and it's important that it delivers the messages from a web server to the android client quickly (that's a synchronizing app).

Also, the internet connection may be unstable (like GPRS). The server application uses `.net 4.5` (may be a windows service or web service)

I've searched around but the answers were not clear for my questions. My questions are as follows:

1. Is it better to use an open socket or check the server every few seconds? (max allowed delay is 15-20 seconds)
2. How much network traffic does a socket use in a day, if it is open and no message passes?
3. How many sockets can be open at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what you want to do, but here are some answers :

1. Reopening a TCP connection every few seconds probably won't hurt. Close+reopen is how most HTTP connections work.
2. An idle TCP socket doesn't send any traffic at all, unless you enable TCP keepalive, but even then it is still very light (and often adjustable).
3. Usually a lot, but is really depends on your software and hardware. A desktop computer may have 1000 open connections on normal load (but can certainly handle more). A big server may handle millions open connections.

Depending on what your 'synchronizing' thing is, you should consider synchronizing with GPS time. It is present on most mobile devices and have a precision around nanoseconds (= all devices will have the same GPS time, give or take some ns). But then the server may need GPS time too, depending on what you do.

Also depending on your application, you should consider using UDP sockets. The good points are that you only need one UDP server socket to handle ALL the UDP clients (you can't do lighter), and that it is more reliable time-wise (when there is a problem, TCP may re-transmit with high delay, while UDP is all or nothing, = you handle up-to-date re-transmit yourself). The downsides are that it is unreliable (messages can be dropped or corrupted, therefore you may want to add some safety), and that some ISP may restrict UDP more than TCP (test yourself to be sure, but usually there is no problems). Note that with UDP, you may need to 'keep alive' yourself, by sending a dummy message, but it is only needed if the 'connection' is idle for too long.

Comment: Thanks,I need sync not for timing. It is like an alarm.Some sensors are available and some peoples should check the sensors. And if an event occurs my application should alarm someone.(That's exactly intelligent remote home control)